# Rails Tutorial Chapter 2, section 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm in section 2.3.3 where we open up the rails console.
I'm then able to retrieve the first_user using

```
first_user = User.first
```

but I get an error with the next command:

```
first_user.microposts
```

Console Message:

```
> first_user.microposts
Micropost Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 1
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: microposts.user_id: SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts"  WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = 1
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:246:in `block in exec_query'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:467:in `select'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:382:in `find_target'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:335:in `load_target'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:44:in `load_target'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /Users/ryentzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is what I THINK is happening. I initially tested both the Users and the Microposts by adding, updating, and deleting users and posts. So I think that the micropost is no longer associated with the first user.

But, I don't know *how* to see which user_id IS associated with the micropost.

I currently have one Micropost:

```
> Micropost.all
Micropost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" => [#<Micropost id: 4, content: "Testing", created_at: "2013-06-10 01:24:34", updated_at: "2013-06-10 01:24:34">]
```

How do I tell which user_id is connected with the micropost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Micropost model has no column named `user_id`. Look at your console output from `Micropost.all` - there's no attribute in the returned instance named `user_id`. Maybe you forgot to run a migration? Maybe you rolled back a migration? Maybe you missed a step completely? When you generated the scaffold, maybe you forgot the part about the user.

Playing around with the app (adding, deleting, editing) won't cause the issue you have. When you retrieve the first user again, and ask to see their miscroposts, if everything was set up properly, you'd get back something - at least an empty relation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go back and see where I missed adding the user_id to the Micropost table.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your error messages and the output from `Micropost.all`, I think you need to add a new column named `user_id` to your `microposts` table. In this way, Active Record can know a `micropost` belongs to which `user` by using the `user_id` column. Maybe you forgot to write or run a migration to add `user_id` column to `microposts` table after you set the relationship between `User` model and `Micropost` model. You can read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations) to know more about Active Record Associations.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the guide.